# Proof with a Vandermonde variant

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, determinant

Currently Studying "Linear Algebra" by Georgi E. Shilov.
I encountered the following problem.

Prove that:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & ... & 1\\
x_1 & x_2 & ... & x_n\\
{x_1}^2 & {x_2}^2 & ... & {x_n}^2\\
. & . & ... & .\\
{x_1}^{n-2} & {x_2}^{n-2} & ... & {x_n}^{n-2}\\
{x_1}^{n} & {x_2}^{n} & ... & {x_n}^{n}
\end{vmatrix} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & ... & 1\\
x_1 & x_2 & ... & x_n\\
{x_1}^2 & {x_2}^2 & ... & {x_n}^2\\
. & . & ... & .\\
{x_1}^{n-2} & {x_2}^{n-2} & ... & {x_n}^{n-2}\\
{x_1}^{n-1} & {x_2}^{n-1} & ... & {x_n}^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix} * \sum_{k=1}^n x_k$$

Immediately I noticed that the matrix on the right is the vandermonde matrix. The first thing I did was to try to find a column or row on the left side matrix to try to do a cofactor expansion that will lead to minors equal to the vandermonde. Unfortunatelly I dont think thats the aproach. Another thing that jumped in is that it has to be related to the row with powers of n-1 since its the biggest difference between them. I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3300187/a-problem-about-vandemonde-matrix

Comment: Thank you Toni Mhax

Comment: I’m still working it over on paper to really grasp it, if the author of that question marked it as an answer I’m assuming it is the proof.